# Is Verilog code with disable named block operation synthesizable?

Tags: verilog, synthesize

Is Verilog code with named block operation synthesizable? One such example is below:

```
 module named_block_disable();

 reg [31:0] bit_detect;
 reg [5:0]  bit_position;
 integer i;

 always @ (bit_detect)
   begin : BIT_DETECT
     for (i = 0; i < 32 ; i = i + 1) begin
       // If bit is set, latch the bit position
       // Disable the execution of the block
       if (bit_detect[i] == 1) begin
          bit_position = i;
          disable BIT_DETECT;
       end  else begin
          bit_position = 32;
       end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Yes it should work.

Answer (score 1):

A named block is always synthesizable - it is the `disable` statement that may have issues with some tools. This usage to get out of a loop should be synthesizable. In SystemVerilog, you would use a `break` statement, which is definitely synthesizable. The `for` loop must be statically unrollable.